# Making a dictionary with sets and values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following lists:

```
keys = ['god', 'hel', 'helo']
values = ['good','god', 'hell', 'hello']
```

I want to create a dictionary like this:

```
{'god':set(['god', 'good']), 'hel':'hell', 'helo': 'hello'}
```

where the key is determined by reducing repeated letters in the value to a single letter.

How would I do this programmatically?

Comment: what is the matching rule exactly?

Comment: How would it decide which values are to be grouped into similar sets?

I assume it's related to your spellcheck trie.

Comment: What's the rule behind associating `good` with `god`?

Comment: I don't see the relationship between `keys`, `values` and your dictionary.

Comment: all repeated letters are reduced to single letters. that will be the key for any of those values/words.

Answer (score 3):

**"all repeated letters are reduced to single letters"**

Actually according to this rule you don't need the `keys` list, because it will be created from the `values`.

Also I would suggest to use a dict of sets for all values, also for the single ones, such as "hell" and "hello". It will make the usage of the dictionary **much** simpler:

```
import itertools as it
values = ['good','god', 'hell', 'hello'] 
d = {}
for value in values:
    d.setdefault(''.join(k for k,v in it.groupby(value)), set()).add(value)

# d == {'god': set(['god', 'good']),
#       'hel': set(['hell']),
#       'helo': set(['hello'])}
```

Comment: A `collections.defaultdict(set)` works great with this approach for Python 2.6 or later.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
import re
import collections

values = ['good', 'god', 'hell', 'hello']
result = collections.defaultdict(set)
for value in values:
    key = re.sub(r'(\w)\1*', r'\1', value)
    result[key].add(value)

# result: defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'hel': set(['hell']), 'god': set(['god', 'good']), 'helo': set(['hello'])})

# if you want to ensure that all your keys exist in the dictionary
keys = ['god', 'hel', 'helo', 'bob']
for key in keys:
    result[key]

# result: defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'hel': set(['hell']), 'god': set(['god', 'good']), 'helo': set(['hello']), 'bob': set([])})
```

Comment: Note that all the values of the dictionary are stored in sets.

Answer (score 0):

Some code golf (sort of - obviously more obfuscation is possible) upon eumiro's answer, observing that itertools.groupby can be used twice (once to get the letter-sets in order of appearance, something I didn't think of - and again to actually create the key-value pairs for the dictionary).

```
from itertools import groupby
data = ['good', 'god', 'hell', 'hello']
dict((''.join(k), list(v)) for k, v in groupby(data, lambda x: zip(*groupby(x))[0]))
```

How it works: each word is first processed with `lambda x: zip(*groupby(x))[0]`. That is, we take the list of (letter, grouper-object) pairs produced by the `groupby` generator, transform it into a pair (list-of-letters, list-of-grouper-objects) (the generator contents are implicitly evaluated for passing to `zip`), and discard the list-of-grouper-objects which we don't want. Then, we group the entire word-list according to the list-of-letters produced by each word, transform the list of letters back into a string, evaluate the grouper-object generators to get the corresponding words, and use those key-value pairs to construct the final `dict`.

Edit: I guess it's cleaner to do the `''.join` step within the lambda:

```
from itertools import groupby
data = ['good', 'god', 'hell', 'hello']
dict((k, list(v)) for k, v in groupby(data, lambda x: ''.join(zip(*groupby(x))[0])))
```